# 'hg strip' created patch is corrupt

Tags: python, mercurial, utf-8, tortoisehg

I used `hg strip` to remove some commits from my history. 
Now I want to reapply the patch that was made as backup during the strip command: `.hg/strip-backup/68a8f24f62d0-backup.hg`

Unfortunately when I try to push the patch, it seems that the patch is corrupted:

```
$:~/sc2$ hg init --mq
adding .hg/patches/68a8f24f62d0-backup.hg
68a8f24f62d0-backup.hg: up to 582 MB of RAM may be required to manage this file
(use 'hg revert 68a8f24f62d0-backup.hg' to cancel the pending addition)
$:~/sc2$ hg qpush
applying 68a8f24f62d0-backup.hg
patch 68a8f24f62d0-backup.hg is empty
transaction abort!
rollback completed
cleaning up working directory...done
abort: decoding near 'h91AY&SY݁��S������': 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 16: invalid start byte!
```

Has someone had this problem already or can give me an advice how to apply the patch? If it is not possible I am more than screwed ...

Maybe this is a python problem?

I tried hg unbundle and get this:

```
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: received file revlog group is empty
```

If I do hg pull:

```
pulling from 68a8f24f62d0-backup.hg
searching for changes
adding changesets
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: data/sc2-local.tar.i@2cad29d699f8: no node!
```

So how can I fix the node problem?

Heinrich

Comment: AFAIK the command `hg unbundle` is used to restore backups made by the strip command - see the output of `hg help strip`.

Comment: A solution for me would be to just get the "healthy" files from the bundle, I can then merge them again to my working copy. The problem is I cannot find a command to get the contents!

Comment: Maybe the file is corrupt indeed. To find the actual problem, it might be useful to run `hg` commands on this file with the `--debug` option. What happens if you run `hg --debug -R <bundle-file> log`?

Comment: Bundles aren't something you can operate on directly -- they're not archive files.  You `hg pull path/to/bundle` to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some contact with Matt Mackall (Primary Mercurial Author) on this topic and we figured out a bug in Mercurial:

Mercurial actually is not able to handle files larger than 2^31-1 Bytes, which are ~2GB, as signed ints are used for saving the size. However, if you add larger files (what I did) mercurial won't reject them but add as usual. The only check for the file size seems to be when pushing to the server. However, I only got a warning and a never ending `hg push` here.

Quote by Matt Mackall from the mail conversation:

> It'll cause an overflow in a few
>   places:
>
> a) when writing the first revision to
>   the revlog, we'll store an
>   uncompressed size modulo 2G, but we'll
>   still be able to successfully read the
>   whole file
>
> b) when building the bundle for
>   transmission or stripping, we'll
>   report a chunk size modulo 2G, which
>   will be interpreted as a negative
>   number and thus look like an empty
>   chunk.

Comment: I think you'll have to admit that tracking 2GB files is not normal version control usage. Your repository will be *enormous* with a bit of modification here and a bit of modification there.

Comment: When you added that file didn't mercurial issue a big warining about adding too big a file?  It used to for anything over 10MB, which I think was raised but not eliminated.

Comment: Sure, to add a 3G file does not make sense and thats why i wanted to use strip!

Comment: Also I did not get a warning with hgtk

Answer (score 5):

From the output of `hg help strip`:

> *Any stripped changesets are stored in ".hg/strip-backup" ... They can be restored by running "hg unbundle .hg /strip-backup/BUNDLE", where BUNDLE is the bundle file created by the strip.*

This simple demo session illustrates the use of the *strip* and *unbundle* commands:

```
# create a new repo and commit some changes:
$ hg init foobar
$ cd foobar/
$ echo a > file
$ hg ci -A -m "Initial"
adding file
$ echo b > file
$ hg ci -m "Change 1"
$ echo c > file
$ hg ci -m "Change 2"
$ hg glog --template '{rev} - {node} - {desc}\n'
@  2 - 86ecd06a38260fd229fdd73ba82efa6b2db0784c - Change 2
|
o  1 - 7827b4d5a10c2ca8d5196752f1b2dec92e8cf573 - Change 1
|
o  0 - 2b41b1e661196fe943125fdb1d590b5a60369c7e - Initial

# trash revision 1 and all its children:
$ hg strip 1
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
saved backup bundle to /path/to/foobar/.hg/strip-backup/7827b4d5a10c-backup.hg
$ hg log --template '{rev} - {node} - {desc}\n'
@ - 2b41b1e661196fe943125fdb1d590b5a60369c7e - Initial

# meanwhile, make new changes:
$ hg ci -m "Change 1.1"
$ hg glog --template '{rev} - {node} - {desc}\n'
@  1 - a5ad2a79835ad0019f215e62fd928f8649cbbcab - Change 1.1
|
o  0 - 2b41b1e661196fe943125fdb1d590b5a60369c7e - Initial

# you decide your previous work was not that bad at all:
$ hg unbundle .hg/strip-backup/7827b4d5a10c-backup.hg
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 2 changesets with 2 changes to 1 files
(run 'hg update' to get a working copy)

$ hg glog --template '{rev} - {node} - {desc}\n'
o  3 - 86ecd06a38260fd229fdd73ba82efa6b2db0784c - Change 2
|
o  2 - 7827b4d5a10c2ca8d5196752f1b2dec92e8cf573 - Change 1
|
| @  1 - a5ad2a79835ad0019f215e62fd928f8649cbbcab - Change 1.1
|/
o  0 - 2b41b1e661196fe943125fdb1d590b5a60369c7e - Initial
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately I cannot execute unbundle without error, see above in my post.